# discord py - Implement stickers in embeds

Tags: discord.py

I make a discord bot and want to display member messages in an embed. So, that's work, but how can I put the Sticker from a member (if he's posting it) into an embed? I read the docs, but it really confuses me.

How can i use the sticker from the user, in the bot embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord currently has not noted that in it's documentation which shows it would not be currently possible (at least in Discord.py)

Stickers also do not have support globally yet, some countries have not got access to Discord stickers which could also potentially affect the use of embeds and cause multiple issues/bugs, in which seems as why they have not added it to the API.

I can't test this myself, as I can't access stickers myself yet, but creating a webhook and sending a sticker in theory should work, hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: I used "sticker.image_url", that's not the gif, but it works with a picture on the very first sticker pack.